# Do Indians need a transit visa in Kuala Lumpur, and if yes how?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, malaysia

I am an Indian travelling from Cochin to Beijing via Kuala Lumpur, using Air Asia. My flight has a layover in Kuala Lumpur of about 10 hours. While booking, it was mentioned that I will need a transit visa in Malaysia and I need to check out and again check in.

1. Do I need a transit visa? If yes, how to get that from KLIA2 airport after checking out?
2. I have a China visa with employment pass endorsed on my passport. Is that enough for travelling from Cochin to Kuala Lumpur?
3. What are the formalities to get a transit visa? Is that straightforward?

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

According to Timatic (the authoritative database used by airlines worldwide)

> Visa required, except for Holders of a valid visa issued by Australia, China (People's Rep.), Chinese Taipei, Japan, Korea (Rep.), New Zealand or USA to nationals of India residing in country of nationality holding confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit For details, click here time of 120 hours, arriving at and departing from Kuala Lumpur (KUL) on Malaysia Airlines (MH) or Air Asia (AK). When transit time is longer than 8 hours it is permitted to leave the transit area if traveling to or returning from the country which issued the visa. (SEE NOTE 48423)
>
> This does not apply to passengers with a Bridging visa E issued by Australia.
>
> NOTE 48423: Transit between Main Terminal and KLIA2 is also permitted. When leaving the airport transit area, passports must be valid for at least 6 months from date of arrival.

You don't need a transit visa at KL