# Do Indian citizens need a transit visa for Malaysia?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, malaysia

I am an Indian Citizen who has lived in Vietnam on a business visa for the last 3 months and a tourist visa for a few months before that.

I am going back to India and my flight is from Ho Chi Minh to Kuala Lumpur by AirAsia (Terminal 2). My next flight 15 hours afterwards from Kuala Lumpur to Pune (Terminal 2) on Indigo airlines

Do I need a transit visa? If so, I am not sure if I am eligible for it given that I'm traveling on two different airlines.

Comment: @david There is lot of contradictory answers which says you need to recheck in the baggage if it's two different airlines

Comment: @AmitJS94: Whether it's two different airlines doesn't matter, but it does matter whether it is two different _tickets_. Is it?

Comment: Actually, I read the answer to the question I linked more closely, it applies only to Sri Lankan citizens, so it's not actually relevant. Sorry about that.

Comment: Here we go: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/109547/11491

Comment: @DavidRicherby Well Beijing is in the list of 8 countries http://www.kln.gov.my/web/ind_chennai/faqs, Sadly Vietnam isn't in that list.

Comment: @AmitJS94 So you need a transit visa. You surely worked that out for yourself without needing me to write it down for you.

Comment: @David Yes hopefully someone with same experience can confirm this,

Comment: @AmitJS94 The answer to the question I linked quotes the visa requirements database used by all the airlines. You should base your decisions on this kind of authoritative information, not on some random person on the internet saying "Yeah, you need a visa."

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes so i need a transit visa - Now to my 2nd question - I am not sure if i am eligible for it as it says - 

Transit pass for 120 hours (without visa) can also be considered to Indian citizen who hold valid permanent residence, expatriate / working pass, student pass, dependent pass any long term visit pass from other countries (please bring along document to proof it).

Does 3 month Business visa from Vietnam count (it expires tomorrow night ) ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "eligible". If you need a visa, you can apply for it. If you meet the criteria, it will be granted.

Comment: Its not clear if i meet the criteria or not.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&AC=VN&AV=Vietnam&DC=IN&DV=India&TC=MY&TV=Malaysia&h=a2ed696c124962ac3df9):

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Nationals of India residing in Viet Nam
> transiting through Kuala Lumpur (KUL) with a confirmed onward ticket
> for a flight to a third country **on Malaysia Airlines (MH) or Air Asia
> (AK) within 120 hours**. They must:
>
> - have a visa issued by Australia, China (People's Rep.), Chinese Taipei, Japan, Korea (Rep.), New Zealand or USA, and
> - arrive at and depart from the same terminal, and
> - **stay in the international transit area of the airport**, and
> - have documents required for the next destination.
>
> This TWOV facility does not apply to passengers with a Bridging visa E (BVE)
> issued by Australia.

Therefore it seems to me that you're out of luck. Your onwards flight is with Indigo airlines and you will need to leave the sterile transit area if you want to re-check luggage. Luckily for you, Indian citizens can apply for a [Malaysian eVisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Malaysia#eVisa) online. As a bonus, that would also let you do some sightseeing in Kuala Lumpur during your layover.